# Git repository can't checkout to existent branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

In my Git repository, I have a branch named "client1" which exists in the remote repository as well. However, when I try to check out or switch to this branch using git checkout client1, I encounter the following error:

```bash
fatal: reference is not a tree: client1
NativeCommandExitException: Program "git.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: 128.
```

But for some other client branch it switch just fine. I've tried to create this branch locally like this:

```bash
git checkout -b client1 origin/client1
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/client1 client1
```

It kind works but I receive an warning always I checkout to this branch `warning: refname 'client1' is ambiguous.` I want to understand why this happens and how can I solve this, I'm actually automating a process of switch to all client branches with GitPython and get theirs diffs against the main branch for specific files, but when I try to checkout to this `client1` branch and probably some others I got this error or the warning about this ambiguity. My issue is about understand the why I can't checkout or switch to this branch even if it exist in the remote references as I checked with `git show-ref --heads | grep 'client1'`.

I will appreciate if some expert can explain if this have something related with "unrelated histories" or some kind of miss configuration.

The repository is being cloned as brand new. and my `git config --global --list` only have the very basic:

```
user.name=SAY-MY-NAME
user.email=guss-maill@company.com
fetch.prune=true
```

About the history of the branches the client1 branch was created based on the main years ago and we casually perform the `git merge main` to bring some changes to the client1 branch. So of course the client1 branch have more commits ahead of main, I'm wondering if that is what creating this issue.

---

Here more details running the command `git cat-file -p origin/client1; git cat-file -p origin/client1^{tree}`. This can be useful for inspecting the contents of specific branches or commits in a Git repository.

```
tree 07a8a9cf1c77ae9bf82ec27a66d2d29d880028cd
parent 44f13b1dea8d46a6cb75c0bc7eec381b2edbe341
author support-adv<support.adv@company.com> 1689602681 -0300
committer support-adv<support.adv@company.com> 1689602681 -0300

client1 - Update version manually IOS
040000 tree 0a871f58d94685e7c10c5a287374b983e8720e90    .fvm
100644 blob 18e95f252defc45e73c3a1f9d8a2a59216a45eea    .gitignore
040000 tree 22f59bec469873082fea408cd1a505b6402a6509    .vscode
100644 blob 3862e40bfbc0450aa40c247472c07eb306c8b2c1    README.md
040000 tree 474a601150e28bdbc37e8fba292176a803aa914a    ReleaseV5
100644 blob 5e948bb1a39a59a539d24a6ac450f71d70ab51ca    diretrizes.md
040000 tree 633a38f482975801a7549a15d9039d0d9a1672cc    smart
```

## Now the info asked for security reason censored

[image]

Comment: `checkout -b` won't fail unless the branch exists _locally_. If that ran fine, it means that the local branch did _not_ exist previously.... And it _now_ exists locally after running the command. If you are then doing `checkout -b` after that with the same parameters, I would expect git to complain as the branch already exists locally. I would like to see the exact command and output. Just in case, it is not required to create local branches.... You can just as easily checkout a remote branch *if there is no need for a local branch_: `git checkout origin/client1`.

Comment: Finally, if you are diffing branches, even if remote, you can do that without doing checkout: `git diff some-remote/some-branch another-remote/another-branch`. It can be done with branches on the same or different remotes, git does not care.... It will always work against the *commits* that the branches (local or remote) point to.

Comment: You can always try `git checkout client1`. If the branch exists locally, it will be checked out.... If the branch does not exist locally but it exists in one (and only one) remote, git will create the branch locally and set the remote branch as its upstream.... If the branch does _not_ exist locally and it exists in more than one remote, then git will complain about it being an ambiguous argument (perhaps the situation you are facing there).

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, now let me give you the exactly commands first the simple clone `git clone https://github.com/account/repo.git source` so it save in the source folder. Then `cd source` then `git checkout client1` so the message `fatal: reference is not a tree: client1
NativeCommandExitException: Program "git.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: 128.`.  So I run ` git show-ref --heads | grep 'client1'` in the git console and it ruturn nothing but the `git ls-remote --heads origin | grep 'client1'` return the `8c8b785....        refs/heads/client1` it means the remote exist

Comment: if I try the same with some other branch like `git checkout client2` this bring me a local branch for this second client. but why? why the client1 can't be created locally? when I use the Git GUI and click in Branch > Checkout > and check `tracking branch` and select the `origin/client1` it says `---------------------------
Git Gui (source)
---------------------------
You are no longer on a local branch.

If you wanted to be on a branch, create one now starting from 'This Detached Checkout'.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
`

Comment: and in the interface GUI the `Current Branch: ` says HEAD when I'm in the client1 `origin/client1` but this means that the `origin/client1` don't exist locally as well, right?

Comment: What do you get with `git branch -r | grep client1`?

Comment: it returns `origin/client1`

Comment: I mean, even with this branch failing to `git checkout client1` it returns that. for other branches like the client2 it also return the `origin/client2` and can checkout to it with `git checkout client2` normally

Comment: Are you working on a shallow clone?

Comment: no, I'm doing the normal clone `git clone https://github.com/account/repo.git source`  if it was the case I probably couldn't checkout to any other branch only the main or the --branch clientX I've selected in the `--depth 1`. But I'm really doing the full clone.

Comment: Is there a `client1` tag?

Comment: no, we don't have tags, you mean the tags we could see aside the branches menu in the GitHub, right? I actually don't even know the propose of a tag, let me check. Ok got it, no we don't have tags like these for releases

Comment: Add the output of these commands to the question: `git cat-file -p origin/client1; git cat-file -p origin/client1^{tree}`

Comment: I see @jthill has an explanation for one of the problems.... I am still wondering about the first error. Sure `client1` is not a tree..... Is there some place where you are forcing that valor to make git that it is the ID of a tree? I am starting to sound paranoid, I know. :-D What can you get from using `GIT_TRACE=1` while running that command?

Comment: `git for-each-ref '**/client1'` without an explicit format asks for the default readout on each, which tells you what it actually refers to.

Answer (score 0):

> It kind works but I receive an warning always I checkout to this branch `warning: refname 'client1' is ambiguous.`

That means you've got multiple refs that match [the convenience rules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) criteria for a bare `client1`.

Say `git for-each-ref '**/client1'` to find all the usual suspects, and `find .git -name client1` to pick up any cthulhu inserts outside the `refs` tree.

To see which one the convenience logic is picking, `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name client1`.

Comment: sorry for the late, I'm too busy in the work, now I just share I'm using these commands, and there is no output. as you can see in the pic I add